# Determine Previous Workgroup Name

Tags: windows-7, workgroup

I have a Windows 7 computer that was on a Workgroup. I needed to change it to be on a domain temporarily. Now, I need to change it back to be on the original Workgroup. My problem is, I can't remember the name of the workgroup (and I'm the administrator :().

Is there a log somewhere that I can review that would help me extract that info? If so, where? thank you so much!

Comment: are there any other devices in "the" workgroup if so look at them for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tony. If other computers are in the workgroup you need only go and check the configuration on one of those machines and then configure the machine you're on to match. If no other computers were on the workgroup, it doesn't matter what name you assign to it.